# how to use rowversion in MS Navision?

Tags: sql, sql-server, navision

I am getting below error when using BLOB image from SQL view.

the table has no rowversion column in the sql server view description.
a rowversion column required when blob fields have been defined

how to fix the issue

I have column rowversion and blob in view.

Comment: Wich NAV version?

Comment: ms navsision 2009 version

Comment: Standardt `BLOB` field or new field? if new was created from NAV or SQL? and what is your error exactly?

Answer (score 1):

We ran into the same issue today.

You need to add a timestamp field to the underlying table and the view, just like NAV would do with a non linked object table.

If you are unable to add an extra field to the linked object (because its from another system that you have no control over), maybe you could alter the view to include a dummy timestamp field. But I haven't tested this.